# How to use methods generated by DataSet Designer in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I created a DataSet using the "Add" button on the solution explorer on Visual Studio to use the DataSet Desginer, then add my tables (The connection was already done) and [created some queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDfNE.png) (everything done from the designer) to get specific data, but how can I use those methods from my code?

I tried a lot of ways but I found nothing:

```
DBDataSet dBDataSet = new DBDataSet();

dBDataSet. //My methods aren't here
dBDataSet.c_Town. //My methods aren't here neither
dBDataSet.c_Town.DataSet. //...
dBDataSet.c_Town.Rows. //...
dBDataSet.c_Town.Columns. //...
```

**So how can I use those methods?** I can't find them anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind...
I was calling the entire class but what I had to call was [the TableAdapter of the respective table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8xKp.png), then I can use those methods:

```
c_TownTableAdapter townTableAdapter = new c_TownTableAdapter();
townTableAdapter.GetNameBy("Town");
```

My bad, but anyways thanks